# Cannot to be cast json

Tags: java, json, eclipse

I am very new to json and I made an example below,
also trying to parse it in a good way though I face issues

I am using Eclipse with:
 **JRE System Library[Java1.8]** 
and using library:
**json-simple-1.1.1.jar**

I have made following JSON file:

```
[
  [
    {
      "TestScenario_1": {
        "Transaction": "A",
        "description": "This is a test A",
        "Co-no": "",
        "Project": "Proj1"
      }
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "TestScenario_2": {
        "Transaction": "B",
        "description": "This is a test B",
        "Co-no": "",
        "Project": "Proj2"
      }
    }
  ]
]
```

Here is my script that try to read the file

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

public class JsonParseTest {

    private static final String filePath = "C:\\temp\\mytest2.json";

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "unused", "rawtypes" })
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {


            // read the json file
            FileReader reader = new FileReader(filePath);

            JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
            JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(reader);

            // get a String from the JSON object
            Long TestScenario=(Long) jo.get("TestScenario");
            System.out.println("TestScenario " + TestScenario);

            String Transaction=(String) jo.get("Transaction");
            System.out.println("Transaction " + Transaction);

            String Description=(String) jo.get("Description");
            System.out.println("Description " + Description);

            String Cono=(String) jo.get("Co-no");
            System.out.println("Co-no " + Cono);

            JSONArray Parameters= (JSONArray) jo.get("Parameters");


        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

though i get following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.simple.JSONArray cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONObject
    at JsonParseTest.main(JsonParseTest.java:25)
```

[image]

Could someone help me out?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can use ObjectMapper, instead of JSONParser.  With ObjectMapper, you can do mapper.readValue(reader, Map.class), that generates a Map<String, Object> with all the information readed from your file.

Comment: Your json file has something extrange.  It has defined an Array of Array of Objects, instead of an Array of Objects.

Comment: Please note that you are not closing the FileReader you had created. An elegant solution to working with streams is to use the try-with-resources feature, which will close the stream instantiated as a resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple approach might be recursive method for the json string both a json array and object with a instanceof method in java.

So, two method needed, the one for json array

```
private static void searchJSONArray(JSONArray arry) {
    JSONArray jarry = arry;
    JSONObject jobj = null;

    for (Iterator iter = jarry.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
        Object o = iter.next();
        if (o instanceof JSONArray) {
            searchJSONArray((JSONArray) o);
        } else if (o instanceof JSONObject) {
            jobj = (JSONObject) o;
            Set keyset = jobj.keySet();

            for (Iterator iter2 = keyset.iterator(); iter2.hasNext();) {
                String key = (String) iter2.next();
                Object value = jobj.get(key);

                if(value instanceof JSONObject)
                {
                    System.out.println("[" + key + "]");
                    searchJSONObject((JSONObject)value);
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println(key + "=" + (String)value);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

and another for json object.

```
private static void searchJSONObject(JSONObject obj) {
    JSONObject jobj = obj;

    Set keyset = jobj.keySet();

    for (Iterator iter2 = keyset.iterator(); iter2.hasNext();) {
        String key = (String) iter2.next();
        Object value = jobj.get(key);

        if(value instanceof JSONObject)
        {
            searchJSONObject((JSONObject)value);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(key + "=" + (String)value);
        }
    }

}
```

Then, the full source is as follows;

```
package com.tobee.tests.parse.json;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;

import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

public class JsonParseTest {

    private static final String filePath = "resource/aa/mytest2.json";

    private static void searchJSONObject(JSONObject obj) {
        JSONObject jobj = obj;

        Set keyset = jobj.keySet();

        for (Iterator iter2 = keyset.iterator(); iter2.hasNext();) {
            String key = (String) iter2.next();
            Object value = jobj.get(key);

            if(value instanceof JSONObject)
            {
                searchJSONObject((JSONObject)value);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println(key + "=" + (String)value);
            }
        }

    }

    private static void searchJSONArray(JSONArray arry) {
        JSONArray jarry = arry;
        JSONObject jobj = null;

        for (Iterator iter = jarry.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
            Object o = iter.next();
            if (o instanceof JSONArray) {
                searchJSONArray((JSONArray) o);
            } else if (o instanceof JSONObject) {
                jobj = (JSONObject) o;
                Set keyset = jobj.keySet();

                for (Iterator iter2 = keyset.iterator(); iter2.hasNext();) {
                    String key = (String) iter2.next();
                    Object value = jobj.get(key);

                    if(value instanceof JSONObject)
                    {
                        System.out.println("[" + key + "]");
                        searchJSONObject((JSONObject)value);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println(key + "=" + (String)value);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            // read the json file
            FileReader reader = new FileReader(filePath);

            JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

            Object jsonThing = jsonParser.parse(reader);

            if (jsonThing instanceof JSONArray) {
                searchJSONArray((JSONArray) jsonThing);
            } else if (jsonThing instanceof JSONObject) {
                JSONObject jobj = (JSONObject) jsonThing;

                Set keyset = jobj.keySet();

                for (Iterator iter2 = keyset.iterator(); iter2.hasNext();) {
                    String key = (String) iter2.next();
                    String value = (String) jobj.get(key);

                    System.out.println(key + "=" + value);

                }
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "unused", "rawtypes" })
    public static void your_main(String[] args) {

        try {

            // read the json file
            FileReader reader = new FileReader(filePath);

            JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
            JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(reader);

            // get a String from the JSON object
            Long TestScenario = (Long) jo.get("TestScenario");
            System.out.println("TestScenario " + TestScenario);

            String Transaction = (String) jo.get("Transaction");
            System.out.println("Transaction " + Transaction);

            String Description = (String) jo.get("Description");
            System.out.println("Description " + Description);

            String Cono = (String) jo.get("Co-no");
            System.out.println("Co-no " + Cono);

            JSONArray Parameters = (JSONArray) jo.get("Parameters");

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

The output is here

```
[TestScenario_1]
Co-no=
Project=Proj1
Transaction=A
description=This is a test A
[TestScenario_2]
Co-no=
Project=Proj2
Transaction=B
description=This is a test B
```

Comment: @Xsi, Have a nice day~~

Comment: The same to you!

Answer (score 0):

Fix your json to:

```
[{
    "Transaction": "A",
    "Description": "This is a test A",
    "Co-no": "",
    "Project": "Proj1"
},
{
    "Transaction": "B",
    "Description": "This is a test B",
    "Co-no": "",
    "Project": "Proj2"
}]
```

And change your implementation with this:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class JsonParseTest {

    private static final String FILE_PATH = "C:\\temp\\mytest2.json";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try (InputStream source = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get(FILE_PATH), StandardOpenOption.READ)) {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);

            // read the json file
            List<Map> jo = mapper.readValue(source, List.class);
            jo.forEach((elem) -> {
                System.out.println("Transaction " + elem.get("Transaction"));
                System.out.println("Description " + elem.get("Description"));
                System.out.println("Co-no " + elem.get("Co-no"));
                System.out.println("Project " + elem.get("Project"));
                System.out.println("***************************************");
            });

            String jsonStr = mapper.writeValueAsString(jo);
            System.out.println("Json content\n" + jsonStr);
        } catch (IOException | NullPointerException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

And executing this, you will have this result:

```
Transaction A
Description This is a test A
Co-no 
Project Proj1
***************************************
Transaction B
Description This is a test B
Co-no 
Project Proj2
***************************************
Json content
[ {
  "Transaction" : "A",
  "Description" : "This is a test A",
  "Co-no" : "",
  "Project" : "Proj1"
}, {
  "Transaction" : "B",
  "Description" : "This is a test B",
  "Co-no" : "",
  "Project" : "Proj2"
} ]
```

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEM:**

The file content is type of JSONArray,

```
[
  [
    {
      "TestScenario_1": {
        "Transaction": "A",
        "description": "This is a test A",
        "Co-no": "",
        "Project": "Proj1"
      }
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "TestScenario_2": {
        "Transaction": "B",
        "description": "This is a test B",
        "Co-no": "",
        "Project": "Proj2"
      }
    }
  ]
]
```

but at line # 24

```
JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(reader);
```

it tried to fetch data(jo) as `JSONObject` so **`ClassCastException`** is occured.

**Solutions:**

- Either change the type of **jo** Object to JSONArray.

```
    JSONArray jo = (JSONArray) jsonParser.parse(reader);
```

- Or Change the file content by keeping a parent of that array.

```
    {
      [
        {
          "TestScenario_1": {
            "Transaction": "A",
            "description": "This is a test A",
            "Co-no": "",
            "Project": "Proj1"
          }
        }
      ],
      [
        {
          "TestScenario_2": {
            "Transaction": "B",
            "description": "This is a test B",
            "Co-no": "",
            "Project": "Proj2"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
[
  {
  "TestScenario_1": {
    "Transaction": "A",
    "description": "This is a test A",
    "Co-no": "",
    "Project": "Proj1"
  }
 },
  {
  "TestScenario_2": {
    "Transaction": "B",
    "description": "This is a test B",
    "Co-no": "",
    "Project": "Proj2"
  }
 }
]
```

then

```
FileReader reader = new FileReader(filePath);

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
JSONArray jo = (JSONArray) jsonParser.parse(reader);

// get a String from the JSON object
JSONObject testScenario=(JSONObject) ((JSONObject)jo.get(0)).get("TestScenario_1");

Long transaction = (Long)testScenario.get("Transaction");
System.out.println("transaction " + transaction);
```

`

use for loop to iterate JSONArray...I am just giving an example

Comment: I get following output by use the change:
TestScenario null
Transaction null
description null
Co-no null

Comment: change "TestScenario" to "TestScenario_1"

Comment: I get following error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
 at JsonParseTest.main(JsonParseTest.java:27)


See example:https://i.imgur.com/WpbABh3.png

Comment: I was doing some editing and you tried in between, just try now...you have to resolve some compile time issues if any